# Addressing columns with $ vs [,"XX"]

Tags: r

I have a rather basic and simple question. I was not able to find a solution anywhere in this forum, partly maybe also due to the fact that searching for symbols like "[]" and "$" is difficult in Google.

In any case, I have come across 2 different ways to address columns in data frames. Consider data frame `df` and column `c1`. I can address this column as follows:

```
df[,"c1"]
df$c1
```

I initially used the syntax with $, however now moved to [] because the former did not work in some cases.

Now my question: are these 2 syntax equivalent? Where is the difference? In which cases in any of them better?

Thanks,
Martin

Comment: Your question is answered in the documentation, which you can access via: `help("Extract")`, `help("[")`, or `help("$")` (all 3 commands will take you to the same documentation).

Comment: The linked question may not be exactly the same, but the accepted answer there will answer your question.